# Onenote on Ubuntu stuck in Youtube

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu version 20.04

I clicked on a video link in Onenote, it took me Youtube page and I have no idea how to get back to OneNote. Toolbars for OneNote are not available. It's behaving as a Youtube app at this point.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found another article indicating that you can press ALT to open a menu and use that to navigate back to the main notebook. That didn't work for me.

For me, I was able to right-click the application icon and click New Window, which opened up a new window that pointed at my notebook.